# how can I get non-pre column when trying to join tables

Tags: hive

I have hive table t1(column a, column b) and table t2(column c column d),when I processing :

`create table t3 as  select * from t1 join t2 on t1.a=t2.c`

I always get the result like this:

```
show table t3;
t1.a t1.b t2.c t2.d
1    3    5    7
2    4    6    8
```

t3's column will be like this : t1.a t1.b t2.c t2.d
how can i get a table(t3) with column a,b,c,d without t1.   t2. ?
please help!

get a table(t3) with column a,b,c,d without t1.t2.

Answer (score 0):

hive should name columns in t3 like a,b,c,d... if you are using a version which isnt doing it, let us know hive version.

As a workaround, you can always mention column names - this gives better column arrangement and control.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS p( x STRING ,y string, z int);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS st( a STRING ,b string, c int);
CREATE TABLE t1 as select * from st join p on a=x;
describe t1;
```

and here is my output. You can see t1 has good column names.

also there is no command like `show table`, you can use `describe mytable;`
[image]